# C++ std features and Binary size

Tags: c++, embedded

I was told recently in a job interview their project works on building the smallest size binary for their application (runs embedded) so I would not be able to use things such as templating or smart pointers as these would increase the binary size, they generally seemed to imply using things from std would be generally a no go (not all cases).

After the interview, I tried to do research online about coding and what features from standard lib caused large binary sizes and I could find basically nothing in regards to this. Is there a way to quantify using certain features and the size impact they would have (without needing to code 100 smart pointers in a code base vs self managed for example).

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but i guess searching for `c++ code bloat` will lead you to tons of *opinions*.

Comment: You can write bloated code with and without the STL or any framework, for that matter. Even if you write every single piece of [library] code yourself, you can still bloat it. There's nothing wrong with using the STL, templates or smart pointers for embedded applications. In fact, I'd even recommend using them, as then you won't shoot yourself. Keep your code DRY and you should be good to go.

Comment: In my experience (using C++ for embedded applications, in the 1990s), the exception handling system, the run time type identification (RTTI), and dynamic memory (`new`/`delete`, `new[]`/`delete[]`, `malloc`/`free`, because we had no heap) were disabled.  Templates were fine, but not used all that much.  Smart pointers were not a thing back then, but would have been irrelevant since we had no heap.  We didn't use I/O Stream facility, but that probably would have been banned as well.

Comment: For certain features you can try to gauge it with Godbolt or just looking at the assembler. For example for templates you have to judge on a case-by-case basis whether using them results in smaller code (less indirection, fewer function calls) or larger one.

Comment: For other stuff you have to look at the linker output. When I did a project like this, I added one feature not realizing that it pulled in the iostreams as a dependency and that part of the standard library alone was larger than my entire memory

Comment: Smart pointers themselves are not very expensive.  They are basically just a reference counter.  Implementing code to redo yourself what they do is only going to increase code size, not decrease it.  The problem is that they rely on exceptions, and in many cases exceptions rely on runtime type information, on stack unwinding code and the corresponding data tables.  The default exception handlers use printf, and that pulls in the whole standard IO library.

Comment: Also most modern C++ code makes very heavy use of the heap.  It usually just assumes that as long as you only want a few kB here and there it is guaranteed to always be available.  This is not the case on embedded systems.  While using the heap doesn't increase code size much, it makes embedded systems very hard to test, because for anything with multiple threads, it is close to impossible to predict your peak usage.  The more code you include that just allocates a small chunk here and there the less deterministic you make the system.

Comment: @TomV `std::unique_ptr` is in fact free, with any sensible optimising compiler.

Comment: The std:: namespace includes the C library as a subset, so clearly not all of `std::`  some of it comes at no overhead.  Parts such as STL containers use templating, under-the-hood dynamic memory allocation and exceptions  that may make them prohibitive in many embedded systems.  Not just for reasons of "size", but also deterministic performance in hard real-time systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question probably deserves more attention than it’s likely to get, especially for people trying to pursue a career in embedded systems. So far the discussion has gone about the way that I would expect, specifically a lot of conversation about the nuances of exactly how and when a project built with C++ might be more bloated than one written in plain C or a restricted C++ subset.

This is also why you can’t find a definitive answer from a good old fashioned google search. Because if you just ask the question “is C++ more bloated than X?”, the answer is always going to be “it depends.”

So let me approach this from a slightly different angle. I’ve both worked for, and interviewed at companies that enforced these kinds of restrictions, I’ve even voluntarily enforced them myself. It really comes down to this. When you’re running an engineering organization with more than one person with plans to keep hiring, it is wildly impractical to assume everyone on your team is going to fully understand the implications of using every feature of a language. Coding standards and language restrictions serve as a cheap way to prevent people from doing “bad things” without knowing they’re doing “bad things”.

How you define a “bad thing” is then also context specific. On a desktop platform, using lots of code space isn’t really a “bad” enough thing to rigorously enforce. On a tiny embedded system, it probably is.

**C++ by design makes it very easy for an engineer to generate lots of code without having to type it out explicitly**. I think that statement is pretty self-evident, it’s the whole point of meta-programming, and I doubt anyone would challenge it, in fact it’s one of the strengths of the language.

So then coming back to the organizational challenges, if your primary optimization variable is code space, you probably don’t want to allow people to use features that make it trivial to generate code that isn’t obvious. Some people will use that feature responsibly and some people won’t, but you have to standardize around the least common denominator. A C compiler is very simple. Yes you can write bloated code with it, but if you do, it will probably be pretty obvious from looking at it.

Comment: I understand the sentiment behind catering to the lowest common denominator, but I don’t agree with it. Hire better people and/or educate the ones you have.

Comment: Excellent point. Time spent babysitting language features is always time you could spend developing your product.

Answer (score 4):

(Partially extracted from comments I wrote earlier)

I don't think there is a comprehensive answer. A lot also depends on the specific use case and needs to be judged on a case-by-case basis.

### Templates

Templates may result in code bloat, yes, but they can also avoid it. If your alternative is introducing indirection through function pointers or virtual methods, then the templated function itself may become bigger in code size simply because function calls take several instructions and removes optimization potential.

Another aspect where they can at least not hurt is when used in conjunction with type erasure. The idea here is to write generic code, then put a small template wrapper around it that only provides type safety but does not actually emit any new code. Qt's QList is an example that does this to some extend.

This bare-bones vector type shows what I mean:

```
class VectorBase
{
protected:
    void** start, *end, *capacity;

    void push_back(void*);
    void* at(std::size_t i);
    void clear(void (*cleanup_function)(void*));
};

template<class T>
class Vector: public VectorBase
{
public:
    void push_back(T* value)
    { this->VectorBase::push_back(value); }

    T* at(std::size_t i)
    { return static_cast<T*>(this->VectorBase::at(i)); }

    ~Vector()
    { clear(+[](void* object) { delete static_cast<T*>(object); }); }
};
```

By carefully moving as much code as possible into the non-templated base, the template itself can focus on type-safety and to provide necessary indirections without emitting any code that wouldn't have been here anyway.

*(Note: This is just meant as a demonstration of type erasure, not an actually good vector type)*

### Smart pointers

When written carefully, they won't generate much code that wouldn't be there anyway. Whether an inline function generates a delete statement or the programmer does it manually doesn't really matter.

The main issue that I see with those is that the programmer is better at reasoning about code and avoiding dead code. For example even after a `unique_ptr` has been moved away, the destructor of the pointer still has to emit code. A programmer knows that the value is NULL, the compiler often doesn't.

Another issue comes up with calling conventions. Objects with destructors are usually passed on the stack, even if you declare them pass-by-value. Same for return values. So a function `unique_ptr<foo> bar(unique_ptr<foo> baz)` will have higher overhead than `foo* bar(foo* baz)` simply because pointers have to be put on and off the stack.

Even more egregiously, the calling convention used for example on Linux makes the caller clean up parameters instead of the callee. That means if a function accepts a complex object like a smart pointer by value, a call to the destructor for that parameter is *replicated at every call site*, instead of putting it once inside the function. Especially with `unique_ptr` this is so stupid because the function itself may know that the object has been moved away and the destructor is superfluous; but the caller doesn't know this (unless you have LTO).

Shared pointers are a different beast altogether, simply because they allow a lot of different tradeoffs. Should they be atomic? Should they allow type casting, weak pointers, what indirection is used for destruction? Do you really need two raw pointers per shared pointer or can the reference counter be accessed through shared object?

### Exceptions, RTTI

Generally avoided and removed via compiler flags.

### Library components

On a bare-metal system, pulling in parts of the standard library can have a significant effect that can only be measured after the linker step. I suggest any such project use continuous integration and tracks the code size as a metric.

For example I once added a small feature, I don't remember which, and in its error handling it used `std::stringstream`. That pulled in the entire iostream library. The resulting code exceeded my entire RAM and ROM capacity. IIRC the issue was that even though exception handling was deactivated, the exception message was still being set up.

### Move constructors and destructors

It's a shame that C++'s move semantics aren't the same as for example Rust's where objects can be moved with a simple memcpy and then "forgetting" their original location. In C++ the destructor for a moved object is still invoked, which requires more code in the move constructor / move assignment operator, and in the destructor.

Qt for example accounts for such simple cases in its [meta type system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmetatype.html#TypeFlag-enum).

Comment: I fell right now into the `stringstream` trap. Do **not** `#include <sstream>`. This costs hundreds of kilobytes of memory. For whatever reason. It will overflow whatever embedded device you have.